# C Program stops as soon as value is returned

Tags: c, error-handling, cs50

I am creating a substitution program for Pset2 of CS50 where I enter a 26 letter key and then some text and it enciphers it given the corresponding letter on the key and when entering a key with duplicate letters it sends the error message and returns 1 as expected however it seems to just stop the program. How can I fix this?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    string key = argv[argc - 1];
    for (int s  = 0; s < strlen(key); s++)
    {
        if (key[0] == tolower(key[s]) || key[0] == toupper(key[s]) )
        {
            printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    
    if (strlen(key) != 26)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int keylen = strlen(key);

    string plaintext = get_string("Enter the plaintext: ");

    char ciphertext [strlen(plaintext)];

    int move[strlen(plaintext)];
    
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    if (keylen == 26)
    {
        for (int counter  = 0; counter < strlen(plaintext); counter++)
        {
            if (plaintext[counter] >= 'a' && plaintext[counter] <= 'z')
            {
                move[counter] = (plaintext[counter]) - 97;
                ciphertext[counter] = key[move[counter]];
            }
            else if (plaintext[counter] >= 'A' && plaintext[counter] <= 'Z')
            {
                move[counter] = plaintext[counter] - 65;
                ciphertext[counter] =key[move[counter]];
            }
            else if (plaintext[counter] < 'A')
            {
                ciphertext[counter] = plaintext[counter];
            }
            else if (plaintext[counter] > 'z')
            {
                ciphertext[counter] = plaintext[counter];
            }
            else if (plaintext[counter] > 'Z' && plaintext[counter] < 'a')
            {
                ciphertext[counter] = plaintext[counter];
            }
        }
        
        for (int loop = 0; loop < strlen(plaintext); loop++)
        {
            if (plaintext[loop] >= 'a' && plaintext[loop] <= 'z')
            {
                printf("%c", tolower(ciphertext[loop]));
            }
            else if (plaintext[loop] >= 'A' && plaintext[loop] <= 'Z')
            {
                printf("%c", toupper(ciphertext[loop]));
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%c", ciphertext[loop]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (key[i] < 'A' || key[i] > 'Z')
        {
            if (key[i] < 'a' || key[i] > 'z')
            {
                printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s the problem, exactly?

Comment: return called from main does indeed generally end execution.  consider making more functions if you wish for a more complex flows with return.  Also consider continue and break in loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues in your code:

- you should check that the key has 26 characters first, then you don't need to compute `strlen(key)` multiple times.
- the initial loop only compares the characters in the key with the first character case independently: that's not enough to assess that there are no duplicate letters.
- testing that the key contains only letters should be performed before reading the string to encypher.  The test is correct for ASCII but somewhat confusing to read. Furthermore the loop should stop at 26, not 27.
- when computing the index of the letter, you should not use magic constants such as `97` or `65`. Use `'a'` and `'A'` instead.
- the `move` array seems useless. The `cyphertext` array should be made one byte longer for the null terminator and constructed with the encoded bytes, including case conversion.
- any error in the key causes the program to output an error message and return `1`, which from the `main` function causes the program to exit with a error status.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    int flag[26] = { 0 };
    unsigned char c;
    int index;

    /* check if letters are contiguous */
    assert('z' - 'a' == 25 && 'Z' - 'A' == 25);

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    string key = argv[1];
    if (strlen(key) != 26) {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        printf("Key must consist of 26 alphabetic characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        c = key[i];
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'b') {
            index = c - 'a';
        } else
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            index = c - 'A';
        } else {
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.");
            return 1;
        }
        if (flag[index]++) {
            printf("Key contains duplicate letter '%c'.\n", c);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    string plaintext = get_string("Enter the plaintext: ");
    char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1];
    
    for (int i = 0; (c = plaintext[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            c = key[c - 'a'];
            c = tolower(c);
        } else
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            c = key[c - 'A'];
            c = toupper(c);
        }
        ciphertext[i] = c;
    }
    ciphertext[i] = '\0';

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, this is supposed to happen.

As the key string is a command-line argument, the program should end if it encounters an error at the command-line level. Then an error message should follow to describe the correct way to use the command.